# Why is setuptools not installing my "data files" named in MANIFEST.in?

Tags: python, setuptools

Trying to use a MANIFEST.in file (contains one line):

```
recursive-include etc *
```

To install some files for systemd (yea, I'm holding my nose about that part)

I see the files get added to the tarball by sdist, but nothing will cause them to install.

setup.py contains the following lines

```
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,
```

Then if I add this to setup.py and remove the MANIFEST.in

```
  data_files=[
      ('etc/systemd/system/', ['etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service'])
  ],
```

they install as expected.  Is there something missing that I need to add for MANIFEST.in to work instead of enumerating all the files by name in setup.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`package_data` and `data_files` are not the same thing.  `package_data` are files that are stored & installed in the same directory as your `*.py` files (hence the "package" part); `include_package_data` thus only marks [data files it finds *inside your package directories*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) (emphasis added) as package data.  Unless your code is stored under `etc/` in your package source, none of your files will be treated as package data.  In order to install files *outside* your Python package directory, [you need to use `data_files`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files), and there is no shortcut as there is with `include_package_data`.

Comment: I checked and this was indeed the case.  Thanks